# Remove Credentials from the end of names in R

Tags: r, regex

**Background**

I'm trying to use the humaniformat package to parse a long list of full names into separate first/last names.  The problem is that many of the names have credentials at the end that are not recognized by the algorithm, so it incorrectly identifies the credential as the last name.

**Question**

How can I remove all credentials in a known set from the end of each name?

The names are formatted as follows:

```
df<-data.frame(Name = c("ADAM WEST RN CDE",
                    "KEVIN CONROY RDN LD CDE",
                    "VAL KILMER RN CNS",
                    "CHRISTIAN BALE RN CDE",
                    "MICHAEL KEATON BS MED PHD"))
ADAM WEST RN CDE
KEVIN CONROY RDN LD CDE
VAL KILMER RN CNS
CHRISTIAN BALE RN CDE
MICHAEL KEATON BS MED PHD
```

And the result I'm looking for:

```
Fixed_Name

ADAM WEST
KEVIN CONROY
VAL KILMER
CHRISTIAN BALE
MICHAEL KEATON
```

I've tried the following but it only removes the first credential listed at the end of the name and leaves the remaining ones.

```
df$Fixed_Name<-gsub(" RN[^A-Z]| CDE[^A-Z]| LD[^A-Z]| RDN[^A-Z]| CNS[^A-Z]
                    | K M[^A-Z]| DO[^A-Z]| PA[^A-Z]| MS[^A-Z]| MSN[^A-Z]
                    | BS[^A-Z]| RPH[^A-Z]| MED[^A-Z]| CDE[^A-Z]
                    | BS[^A-Z]| MED[^A-Z]| PHD[^A-Z]"," ",df$Name)
```

Comment: What about `trimws(gsub("CDE|RN|CNS|MED|BS|PHD|RND|LD", "", df$Name))`?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik That would cause a problem with names like `trimws(gsub("CDE|RN|CNS|MED|BS|PHD|RND|LD", "", "HAROLD"))`

Comment: Try just keeping two first names - `sub("^(\\S+\\s+\\S+).*", "\\1", df$Name)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this

```
rex <- "( (RN|CDE|LD|RDN|CNS|K M|DO|PA|MS|MSN|BS|RPH|MED|PHD))*$"
df$Fixed_Name<-gsub(rex,"",df$Name)
df
#                        Name     Fixed_Name
# 1          ADAM WEST RN CDE      ADAM WEST
# 2   KEVIN CONROY RDN LD CDE   KEVIN CONROY
# 3         VAL KILMER RN CNS     VAL KILMER
# 4     CHRISTIAN BALE RN CDE CHRISTIAN BALE
# 5 MICHAEL KEATON BS MED PHD MICHAEL KEATON
```

Here we look for `<space>title` zero or more times at the end of the string and remove it.

Answer (score 2):

you can add the meta character `(.*)` to account for that, here is the solution

```
> df<-data.frame(Name = c("ADAM WEST RN CDE",
+                         "KEVIN CONROY RDN LD CDE",
+                         "VAL KILMER RN CNS",
+                         "CHRISTIAN BALE RN CDE",
+                         "MICHAEL KEATON BS MED PHD"))
> 
> df$Fixed_Name<-gsub(" RN[^A-Z](.*)| CDE[^A-Z](.*)| LD[^A-Z](.*)| RDN[^A-Z](.*)| CNS[^A-Z](.*)
+                     | K M[^A-Z](.*)| DO[^A-Z](.*)| PA[^A-Z](.*)| MS[^A-Z](.*)| MSN[^A-Z](.*)
+                          | BS[^A-Z](.*)| RPH[^A-Z](.*)| MED[^A-Z](.*)| CDE[^A-Z](.*)
+                          | BS[^A-Z](.*)| MED[^A-Z](.*)| PHD[^A-Z](.*)"," ",df$Name)
> df
                       Name      Fixed_Name
1          ADAM WEST RN CDE      ADAM WEST 
2   KEVIN CONROY RDN LD CDE   KEVIN CONROY 
3         VAL KILMER RN CNS     VAL KILMER 
4     CHRISTIAN BALE RN CDE CHRISTIAN BALE 
5 MICHAEL KEATON BS MED PHD MICHAEL KEATON
```